# What's the actual class of a has_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Basic primer:

```
class User 
  has_many :programs, :through => :memberships
  has_many :memberships
end

class Program
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :program
end
```

Console:

```
User.new.save
Program.new.save
User.programs << Program.first

User.first.programs.class
# => Array
User.first.programs.methods.grep /where/
# => []
User.first.programs.where :id => 1
# => [#<Program id: 1>]
User.first.programs.where(:id => 1).class
# => ActiveRecord::Relation
```

So the question is that `User.first.programs`, the has_many method, seems to return a result that barks like an `ActiveRecord::Relation` and accepts methods like a `Relation`, but self-identifies as an `Array` and shares its methods with an instance of class `Array`.

So what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indeed surprising and don't know if it was the best solution, but at least it's documented (in the [AssociationProxy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy) class):

> the association proxy in blog.posts
>   has the object in blog as @owner, the
>   collection of its posts as @target,
>   and the @reflection object represents
>   a :has_many macro.
>
> This class has most of the basic
>   instance methods removed, and
>   delegates unknown methods to @target
>   via method_missing. As a corner case,
>   it even removes the class method and
>   that’s why you get
>
> blog.posts.class # => Array though
>   the object behind blog.posts is not an
>   Array, but an
>   ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation.

Comment: Indeed, one of the freakier parts of Rails (and Ruby for that matter). Of course, the follow-up question is: How does one handle this situation other than praying for documentation?  There's a SO question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446331/metaprogramming-how-to-discover-the-real-class-of-an-object

Comment: Ruby's dark magic comes by design, and that's ok, so I'd say the best way to avoid this kind of problems is simply "don't do it". I didn't check, but I think (I hope) it's done differently in Rails 3.

Comment: I agree, as long as you know there is dark magic going on it's okay.  But it is scary when it happens and is not well documented, so it would be nice to have a reliable way to detect and work with these situations.  I just feel like there must be a way to get the REAL class.