# Metaprogramming: How to discover the real class of an object?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I was kidding with metaprogramming in Ruby and I did this code:

```
class Class
  def ===(other)
    other.kind_of?(self)
  end
end
class FakeClass
  def initialize(object)
    methods.each {|m| eval "undef #{m}" if m.to_sym != :methods }
    define = proc do |m|
      eval(<<-END)
        def #{m}(*a, &b)
          @object.#{m}(*a, &b)
        rescue Object
          raise $!.class, $!.message.gsub("FakeClass", @object.class.to_s),
                $!.backtrace-[$!.backtrace[-caller.size-1]]
        end
      END
    end
    object.methods.each {|m| define[m] }
    def method_missing(name, *a, &b)
      if @object.methods.include?(name.to_s)
        define[name]
        eval "@object.#{name}(*a, &b)"
      elsif @object.methods.include?("method_missing")
        eval "@object.#{name}(*a, &b)"
      else
        super
      end
    rescue Object
      raise $!.class, $!.message.gsub("FakeClass", @object.class.to_s),
            $!.backtrace-[$!.backtrace[-caller.size-1]]
    end
    @object = object
  end
end
```

This creates a fake class that mimics a object. Look:

```
a = FakeClass.new(1)  # => 1
a.class               # => Fixnum
a.methods             # => Return all Fixnum methods
a + 1                 # => 2 (is not a FakeClass)
Fixnum === a          # => true
a.something           # => NoMethodError:
                      #    undefined method `something' for 1:Fixnum
class Fixnum
  def foo
    true
  end
end

a.foo                 # => true
```

The problem is, now I don't know how to know if a object is real or fake. In others words, if `#class` returns the true class of the object. Exist some pure ruby way to differentiate?

Think in a scenario where I don't know that FakeClass exist or I don't know what is the name of the FakeClass. It means I can't edit the FakeClass to add a method like `#is_fake?`.

PS: I know that `a.instance_eval {self}` returns the object (not fake). But it doesn't help to check if `a` is fake.

Comment: Note that the ability for one object to simulate another object in such a way that it cannot be distinguished from the real thing is the *essence* of OO. In other words: it *must* be possible to create such a fake object, otherwise Ruby wouldn't be OO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another answer:

```
a = FakeClass.new(1)
b = 1
da = Marshal.dump(a)
db = Marshal.dump(b)
puts da == db            #=> false
```

Comment: Cool! I can't think in a way to block it now. Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you modify how the `FakeClass` marshals itself?

Answer (score 1):

A facetious answer: change Fixnum and see if it sticks. It is rather specific to this method of proxying, I guess, but it will do the job.

```
class Fixnum
  def foo
    return true
  end
end

a.foo # NoMethodError
```

I should make this into a nice function, but lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have FakeClass implement #class,  and return `FakeClass`

such as:

```
class FakeClass
  #code
  def class
    FakeClass
  end
end
```

To see what class is the object you are proxying, just call

```
a.object.class #=> Fixnum
```

Answer (score 0):

For *that* FakeClass, I know about the @object, and I'd try:

```
a = FakeClass.new(5)

class << a
  def fake?
    self.instance_variable_defined? :@object
  end
end

a.fake?  #=> true
```

About an unknown FakeClass, I'd compare the number of instance variables:

```
fake = (a.instance_variables.length > 1.instance_variables.length)
```

Comment: Have you tried that? The first raises `TypeError: can't define singleton method "fake?" for Fixnum`. The second returns false. `#instance_variable_defined?` and `#instance_variables` were redefined and return the value from the `@object`.

Comment: @LBg Yes, you're right! It seems hard to break your code! ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can define any method you want in FakeClass and check for it with respond_to?

```
a = FakeClass.new(1)

a.respond_to?( 'is_fake_class?' )
```

for instance.

Comment: Unless the faker's decided to fix `respond_to?` (which you ought to do whenever you modify `method_missing`).

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing.  And if you think this is just playing around, try digging through Rails ActiveRecord associations (Specifically: [AssociationProxy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/AssociationProxy)) and you'll find exactly this kind of magic (the scary kind!) going on.

Here is one way that I ran across to at least detect this kind of thing:

```
a = FakeClass.new(5)
Fixnum.instance_method(:class).bind(a)
```

throws:

```
TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of Fixnum
```

I feel like there must be a better way though.

Comment: In fact, this kind of implies there's a better way since the Ruby interpreter clearly knows better than to trust a.class.  But I'm not sure how to get access to this knowledge.